# Closed sets in Spec(k[X,Y])

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

On page 74 of Mumford's red book (attached) it is stated that a proper closed set in Spec(k[X,Y]) is composed of finitely many irreducible curves and finitely many closed points. Why does such a union need to be finite? Also, he states that given a closed subset of the set of closed points in the classical Zariski topology, there is a unique set of non-closed points to add to get a closed set in the new topology. Is a closed subset of the set of closed points in the classical topology not closed in the modern? Thanks![image: Mumford text]

Comment: What is «the modern topology»?

Comment: I mean V(A) defined as the set of primes containing A, rather than the set of maximals containing A.

Comment: I pray to Superman that is not an original copy of a book you've written on.

Answer (score 1):

To see why it needs to be a finite union:

Let $A$ be a closed set so that $A=\bigcup V(I_i)$ for ideals $I_i$. Then $A=V(\bigcap I_i)$ by properties of the Zariski topology. Since $k[x,y]$ is Noetherian, there are only finitely many minimal primes (call them $P_j$) over $\bigcap I_i$ so that this reduces to the case of $A=V(P_1)\cup \cdots \cup V(P_n)$.

For the second question, it would probably be easier to think of what Mumford is saying like this:

Clearly the ring is invariant in the correspondence between the classical affine space and Zariski topology and the spectrum and the Zariski topology on the spectrum. So if we take a closed subset of affine space, the closed points of this set correspond to a set of maximal ideals in our ring. If we now consider this set of maximal ideals in our ring, but corresponding to points in the spectrum, the closure of this the points of the spectrum includes new points (non-closed, generic points).

Comment: This makes sense, however $V(P_i)$ in the finite union is the set of primes containing $P_i$ which need not be finite correct? $V(P_i)$ is not one of the closed points or irreducible curves that Mumford mentions, but rather the closed points and irreducible curves compose $V(X_i)$ correct?

Comment: @kfriend You're right, the points of the set $V(P_i)$ need not be finite in number (if $k$ is an infinite algebraically closed field then the curve $V(P_i)$ has infinitely many points, all of which are maximal ideals containing $P_i$). No, $V(P_i)$ are exactly the irreducible curves or closed points not contained in an irreducible curve (in fact, they are the irreducible components of the variety $A$).

Comment: I guess my confusion is thus, when do we regard $V(P_i)$ as the vanishing set of the ideal $P_i$, in which case it is either a point or an irreducible curve, and when we regard it as the set of prime ideals containing $P_i$, in which case it could be a point or what, just a set of primes?

Comment: @kfriend It just takes time. Think about it geometrically: if a function vanishes on a variety, then it must vanish on all points of the variety. This means if a function vanishes on $V(P)\subset Spec(R)$ then it vanishes at all points $Q\in V(P)$ which is obvious in the geometric picture. Mumford tends to think very geometrically and his text reflects this point of view. I would say for the time being think about it geometrically and then try to fit the geometric picture into the algebraic picture when you want to prove things about algebra (or vice versa).

Comment: But how can we just jump back and forth between effectively defining $V(P)$  as the set of maximals containing $P$ (equiv points vanishing on $P$, and then as the set of primes containing P? It seems like these two definitions are treated as equivalent. Thanks for all of your help

Comment: @kfriend It is not defined via maximal ideals (unless you mean the maxspec). A point of $V(P)$ could be a generic point of an irreducible variety. For example the point $P=(x^2+y^2-1)$ is a generic point of the circle and containing it are all ideals $Q_i=(x-a,y-b)$ on the circle. So if $P$ is a point of $V(I)$ so are all of the $Q_i$. Longer chains can be found in higher dimension than the dimension of $k[x,y]$.

Comment: I guess I was just thinking that V(P) regarded as the vanishing set of P could be regarded as the set of maximal ideals containing P (the maximal ideals being (X-a,Y-b), for (a,b) vanishing on P), whereas in the topology on Spec it's the primes containing P. Hence given the vanishing set of some ideal I, V(I), this defines the set of maximal ideals containing I. Then I assumed what Mumford meant by "adding a finite set of non closed points to get s closed set in our new plane" was adding the primes containing I to the maximals we already had.

Comment: @kfriend That's the idea!

Comment: Great, but then what is this whole notion of adding finitely many non closed points to get a closed set in the new topology, given one in be "old." The extra primes needed could obviously be infinitely many in number.

Comment: @kfriend I showed in my answer there are only finitely many irreducible components and since the krull dimension is 2 you can write out the ideals to see why there are only finitely many (hint: what is an irreducible subset of a curve).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Last question: when you gave the example of a generic point if a circle, contained in the maximal ideals $Q_i=(x-a, y-b)$, are these the only prime ideals containing $P$? In general, is $V(P)$ for P prime composed only of a generic point and maximal ideals?

Comment: @kfriend Only in krull dimension 2. In higher dimensions it there can be longer chains.

Answer (score 0):

(In this answer I will primarily use $k=\mathbb{C}$, since I think $\mathbb{C}$ gives us a better "picture", being more familiar)

You seem to be confusing two topologies on $\mathbb{C}^2$. By "classic topology", I assume you mean the standard topology induced by the standard metric. This is different from the Zariski topology (which I assume you meant by "modern topology"). As you point out $\mathbb{C}^2$ with Zariski topology is very different from $\mathbb{C}^2$ with the standard topology you might be used to. To get a sense of Zariski topology, you should think that open sets are VERY big in Zariski topology, whatever that means.

For example, let's take $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x]$, which you can think of as $\mathbb{C}$ (Here, it is important to remember that the **closed** points of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$ are identified with $\mathbb{C}$ since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed). Then, in standard topology, closed sets are finite unions of closed intervals, or the entire $\mathbb{C}$. However, a closed set in Zariski topology is simply a **finite set of points**. Eoin's answer explains why and another easy way to see this is by noticing that a polynomial $f\in \mathbb{C}[x]$ has only finitely many zeros. Since $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a PID, any maximal ideal is generated by some $f$ and thus, closed sets are zeros of polynomials. This means that Zariski **open** sets of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x]$ are precisely those whose complement is a finite set of points.

The case of $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]$ is similar to the case above. The Zariski closed sets are going to be finite unions of loci where the ideal "vanishes" i.e. curves and closed points.

**NOTE** The statement is true even when $k$ is not algebraically closed. However, if $k$ is not algebraically closed, $\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]$ does not "look like" $k^2$. More precisely, the closed points of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]$ do not correspond to points of $k^2$. You can try seeing what the closed points of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}[x]$ are and it will give you a good idea. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ for $k$ algebraically closed. Then irreducible closed subsets are  $\mathbb{A}^2_k, V((f))$ for $f$ irreducible and $V((x-a,y-b))$. Thus, the closed subsets are the whole space, finite collection of points and irreducible curves.

An arbitrary closed subset in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ just looks like  a bunch of points in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$.

This is the old topology.

By considering $\mathbb{A}^2_k \subset spec(k[x,y])$ we realise the bunch of points in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ is not a closed set in $spec(k[x,y])$. What we need to do to get closed subsets is just add the non-closed points. This exactly corresponds to addings points like $(f)$ or $(0)$ (thinking of them as elements in $spec(k[x,y]) )$.

[image]